Struggling to enable unsafe sysctl for opensearch in k8
I am somewhat new to k8 and I am trying to utilise the helmchart to start up opensearch.
My setup is as follows:

XUbuntu 24.04(Running in virtualbox)
Rancher 1.15.0
k8 - 1.30.3
Opentofu 1.8.1

Looking at the documentation the I realise the kubernetes_pod_security_policy has been deprecated as of k8 1.25. However I am not sure how else to go about enabling unsafe sysctls.
Listed below are the opentofu helm resource I am using and the values.yml I am overriding:
resource "helm_release" "opensearch" {
  name        = "opensearch"
  namespace   = kubernetes_namespace.monitoring.metadata.0.name
  repository  = "https://opensearch-project.github.io/helm-charts"
  chart       = "opensearch"
  version     = "2.22.0"

  values = [
    "${file("opensearch.yml")}"
  ]

  depends_on = [helm_release.traefik]
}

and opensearch.yml:
extraEnvs:
  - name: OPENSEARCH_INITIAL_ADMIN_PASSWORD
    value: yourStrongPassword123
plugins:
  security:
    ssl:
      http:
        enabled: false
persistance:
  enabled: false
sysctl:
  enabled: true
sysctlInit:
  enabled: true
initResources:
  limits:
     cpu: "1000m"
     memory: "900Mi"
  requests:
     cpu: "25m"
     memory: "128Mi"

Listing the pods I can see the following indicating the sysctl has not been configured
opensearch-cluster-master-0                                0/1     Terminating       0          0s
opensearch-cluster-master-2                                0/1     SysctlForbidden   0          0s

from the events in k8:
29s         Warning   SysctlForbidden         pod/opensearch-cluster-master-2                                               forbidden sysctl: "vm.max_map_count" not allowlisted
28s         Warning   SysctlForbidden         pod/opensearch-cluster-master-2                                               forbidden sysctl: "vm.max_map_count" not allowlisted
28s         Normal    Scheduled               pod/opensearch-cluster-master-2                                               Successfully assigned monitoring/opensearch-cluster-master-2 to lima-rancher-desktop
27s         Normal    Scheduled               pod/opensearch-cluster-master-2                                               Successfully assigned monitoring/opensearch-cluster-master-2 to lima-rancher-desktop
27s         Warning   SysctlForbidden         pod/opensearch-cluster-master-2                                               forbidden sysctl: "vm.max_map_count" not allowlisted


Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

you can follow this issue to fix it.

Many thanks Arta. Much appreciated
